# How do I move from a relational database and do I need to?

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

I'm currently building a CRM for a niche industry that can be tailored for the end user. We currently are using a base table for leads and then basically a hacked together combination of tables as a key/value store for any custom fields that might be added.

Each lead in the CRM also has tables for various owners, permissions, access logs, scheduled tasks, and generated contracts/documents.

Currently, everything is stored in a MySQL database but it just seems really messy. I'm thinking of using a NoSQL solution like MongoDB and then using Redis to create any relationships between tables.

Example: I'm thinking of storing the leads and users in a MongoDB database and then using Redis for storing what users a certain lead belongs to etc.

Just looking for some general advice on what the best solution is for this situation as I haven't dealt with NoSQL before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. mysql is a great tool
2. storages is not some stuff that works automagically. For being working well - the great developer needs to implement great schema and great code.

What I wanted to say: if you have some issues now - it doesn't mean that they will disappear once you moved to another database (paradigm, ideology, etc). Even if they moved away - the new ones will come. Nothing happens without hard working.

And especially to big volumes of data and high loaded projects - there is no general advice and silver bullet.

ps:

> I'm thinking of using a NoSQL solution like MongoDB and then using Redis to create any relationships between tables.

MongoDB **can** maintain relations. This is one more argument to not move to the databases you are not well experienced in.

Comment: +1 for stress on good design and implementation rather than on technology.

Comment: Perhaps, I should explain the current "problem" I'm having.

I have a large number of "custom keys" that are created based on each company that uses the CRM. To manage all of these I have a table called custom_schema that is basically a list of each of the custom columns and what type they are. Then I have tables called custom_int, custom_string, etc. that store the data for the custom schema. However, this is a very slow methodology as when there are thousands of leads in the database it really slows down everything.

Comment: @Adam: then probably mongodb can be a good solution, since it is document oriented and EAV in rdbms is terrible ;-)

Comment: I'm also a bit concerned on whether Mongo is the best solution for all of my MySQL tables. Although It'd be nice to only use one database, it seems like Mongo wouldn't be a great choice to store user permissions, groups, and roles compared to MySQL. But then again, I am just starting to explore Mongo.

Comment: @Adam: uhm, i don't know how you store your permissions and other things, but mongo is a *very* powerful tool, which definitely can replace relation dbms (i don't say it is simple, but it is possible).